# Copy range to destination and return destination range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I would like to copy a range to a new location in such a way that it returns the new range, which I can then store in a variable for further processing.

I gather the usual way of copying cells is to use the Range.Copy method:

```
Dim rCopiedRange As Range, rRangeToCopy as Range, rStartLocation as Range
Set rRangeToCopy = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C4:F10")
Set rStartLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2")
rRangeToCopy.Copy rStartLocation
```

But since this is a method I can't set the result to a variable and

```
Set rCopiedRange = rRangeToCopy.Copy rStartLocation
```

is a syntax error.

How can I copy the range to a new location in such a way that the new range (in this case range A2 to D6 of Sheet 2) is stored as a variable?

Comment: i think something is wrong, D6 or D10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) method as you know the size of destination range will be the same as the source range.

```
Set rCopiedRange = rStartLocation.resize(rRangeToCopy.rows.count,rRangeToCopy.columns.count)
```

Using Resize, you could transfer the range directly without involving the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rCopiedRange As Range, rRangeToCopy As Range, rStartLocation As Range
    Dim Rows As Long, Columns As Long

    Set rRangeToCopy = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C4:F10")
    Set rStartLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2")

    rRangeToCopy.Copy rStartLocation

    Rows = rRangeToCopy.Rows.Count
    Columns = rRangeToCopy.Columns.Count

    Set rCopiedRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range(Cells(rStartLocation.Row, rStartLocation.Column), Cells(Rows + 1, Columns))

End Sub
```